# agetty dumb terminal option

Tags: linux, centos, console, serial-port, getty

I'm trying to set up a CentOS distro to output on a serial console. I went through all the steps described [on this page](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/centos-rhel-6-install-serial-console/) .

My question concerns the agetty command:

> exec /sbin/agetty ttyS1 19200 vt100-nav

Would it be possible to specify a dumb terminal type as the last command line option so that it only sends plain ASCII? I don't really care for vt100 escape characters, since it would complicate my parsing code on the other end of the serial connection.

Answer (score 0):

The `agetty` program only sets `TERM`, does not affect the way the terminal operates (other than initializing the connection).  Any initialization that is concerned with the value of `TERM` would be in your shell.

The shell in turn will check the terminal database; you may find `"dumb"` or `"unknown"` works with your shell.

Further reading:

- [agetty - alternative Linux getty](http://linux.die.net/man/8/agetty)
- [Remote Serial Console HOWTO: 6.3. agetty](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Remote-Serial-Console-HOWTO/getty-agetty.html)